# Old site in Magento 1 (1.9.2.3 probably) no longer displaying properly

Tags: magento-1.9, backup

Good evening friends,

I've lost contact with my developer years ago and kept running the same M1 backup i had from 2017 whenever something stopped working. However, now that fails too, even if i erase everything and put the 2017 backup or load a backup from when the site worked, it doesn't load anymore. Please be kind and share some thoughts so that i can restore the backup i have and have it run until i manage to build the new site. [www.casafoca.ro](https://www.casafoca.ro)

current errors are visible since i edited the sample.xml in errors to show them: There has been an error processing your request The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded

Trace: #0 /home/drapajer/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(248): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->setFetchMode(2) #1 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(175): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array) #2 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Array) #3 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write') #4 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write') #5 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter() #6 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter() #7 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection() #8 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website)) #9 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website)) #10 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website)) #11 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website)) #12 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection() #13 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(619): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection() #14 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(477): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores() #15 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store') #16 /home/drapajer/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) #17 /home/drapajer/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store') #18 {main}

Thank you very much, Have a good night Kind regards Horace p.s. feel free to drop me a whatsapp @ +40722600887 if you like

Comment: This sounds like a missing php extension - did your hoster update your php version recently? Maybe you can ask them, how to (re-)activate the pdo php extension.

Comment: @mario Good morning, thank you for your reply.
I had a look, i have PhP Version 7.2 installed with these checks in place :

pdo   <--- so it's active
pdo_dblib
pdo_firebird
pdo_mysql
pdo_oci
pdo_odbc
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pdo_sqlsrv

So i checked the rest as well.
The error persists even if i set PHP Version to 5.3 / 5.4 / 5.5 / 5.6 / 7.0 / 7.1  up to 7.2 which is current.

Any other ideas?
Thank you for your time and help
Have a nice day
Kind regards
Horace

Comment: You can try to add these lines to your php.ini file inside your magento folder:

extension = pdo.so
extension = pdo_sqlite.so
extension = sqlite.so
extension = pdo_mysql.so

Comment: Thank you Mario. I looked for the php.ini without too much luck, found one in the root through search function that was called php.ini.sample and renamed it to php.ini + edited . Can you please have a look ?https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IHSNgOxEng9zuyDi49C2qF2gpQN6VUdh/view?usp=sharing  . Should i place this file in another place or does it work at the root? Thank you once again for bearing with and aiding me

Comment: ok, I had to look it up for myself - Those lines have to be added into the global php.ini file. To find the used file, see this link: https://devanswers.co/ubuntu-php-php-ini-configuration-file After editing the file, you should reload/restart apache2, so that the changes take effect.

Comment: Can i use any CLI commands to refresh the status? I have terminal with SSH available. And i downloaded packages of 1.923 / 19.24 and latest 1.93X that i can extract clean files from, in case something is missing (which i doubt). I don't think php.ini existed back then >.>

Comment: what do you mean by "refresh status"? Normally, you could restart/reload apache over cli. The command depends on your Linux distribution.

Comment: I meant to clear cache, reindex everything. i used those before, years ago. Would a clear cache help with restoring a backup that used to work 99% of the times it was used? Is it possible that no php.ini file is used by a magento instance? Perhaps i can add those lines someplace else?

Comment: clearing cache is only possible via php (run a php script from cli) - and magento itself dont uses php.ini - your webserver uses it.

Comment: Looks like my hoster replied : They're using cpanel with Select PHP Version, no php.ini, and as OS -> cloudlinux (modified centos) with litespeed web server (older version of apache modified & optimized)
CLI commands available via cpanel terminal for SSH

Comment: Fixed, went for native 5.6 php and it works again. Thanks for all the efforts so far!

Comment: Time to do a backup and set up a backup server or time to start setting up magento 2 ;-)